# Reuso de chamadas AJAX com jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ola

E muito comum ver pela internet blocos de chamadas ajax que sempre repetem exaustivamente a mesma estrutura, eu gostaria de melhorar minhas chamadas usando padroes de parametrizacao e poupar codigo de meus processos.

Padrao atual:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 30000,
        data: 
        {
            //parametros
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            //caso sucesso...
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //caso erro
        },
    });
```

Eu gostaria de propor uma função que fosse centralizadora, algo como
**chamarAjax("POST", url, array(parametros))**

Mas ai é que surgem as dúvidas:
1) Considerando que parametros pode ser uma array (chave/valor) como passar eles considerando que podem ser 'n' ?

2) Como trabalhar com o retorno da função executada (success, error, complete) no processo/script que chamou a função ?

Eu busquei exemplos desse paradigma mas não encontrei nada, agradeço qualquer indicação

Comment: Você pode ao invés de usar o ajax utiliar o AXIOS.
Ele reduz um pouco o código que é utilizado.
https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Obrigado @LucasBrogni pela indicação, vou avaliar

Comment: pq não utilizar o $.post e o $.get?

Comment: @TobiasMesquita nada contra, o ponto não se trata deles em sí, mas sim, de concentrar chamadas. Por exemplo ao inves de ter um $.get('usuario/blablabla') e toda sua configuração (com timeout por exemplo) eu queria ter algo mais simples em mãos

Comment: Não pode por numa function com todos os parametros?

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim, essa é a idéia ! Mas quando falo de parametros como data (ou seja um array) e ao mesmo tempo, como interceptor success/error/, voce por acaso tem algum exemplo ?

Comment: @dvd valeu por compartilhar, vou avaliar !

Comment: ia postar algo parecido com o @dvd postou, mas o exemplo dele está muito bom, aproveitando o `done` para chamar a função e retornando *data*, muito bom

Comment: @dvd ficou perfeito o que você mandou, deu para explorar bem e gerar para meu padrão sem problemas. Mais uma vez obrigado !

Comment: Que bom... vou postar como resposta pq me deu trabalho rs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jovem, a chamada de `$.ajax` retorna uma `Promise` (bem provável que não seja a nativa, mas sim a do jQuery). Dessa forma, é possível que você chame uma função que retorne essa `Promise`, permitindo parâmetros, como a função `$.ajax` já faz, porém deixando parâmetros pré-definidos. Assim, você pode combinar a chamada de `$.ajax` e `$.extend` para aumentar o poder de reutilização.

Vou dar um exemplo pra você de como faço quando preciso fazer upload de arquivos com jQuery. Eu costumo utilizar as pré-definições dentro de uma função, mas não deixando o código engessado:

```
function ajaxUpload(options)
{

    options = $.extend({}, {
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
    }, options);


    return $.ajax(options);
}
```

Dessa forma, a chamada poderia ser feito dessa forma:

```
ajaxUpload({
    url: '/upload/imagem',
    data: data,
}).success(function () {
    console.log('upload da imagem concluído')
})


ajaxUpload({
    url: '/upload/texto',
    data: data,
    success: function () {
       console.log('upload do texto concluído')
    }
})
```

Observe que faço duas chamadas, reaproveitando as mesmas "configurações" do Ajax. Importante notar que na segunda chamada eu uso o `success` como parte do `options`, mostrando que é possível ter alta usabilidade tanto no retorno quanto pelo parâmetro.

**Observação**: Dependendo do seu uso, você nem mesmo precisa criar uma função, já que o jQuery tem vários métodos para facilitar requisição Ajax, pois já têm as opções de requisição pré-definidas.

Por exemplo:

- `$.post` - Define uma requisição com o método POST
- `$.get`  - Define uma requisição GET
- `$.getJSON` - Define uma requisição que retorna `JSON` já "parseado".

Exemplificando o uso do `$.post`:

```
  $.post('/url', {id: 1}, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
  })
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta e pelo conhecimento, realmente ficou bem mais 'elegante' dessa forma. Se não for pedir demais, poderia dar uma ajuda nesse topico :  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/314278/chamar-m%C3%A9todo-ajax-sincrono-sem-asyncfalse

Answer (score 0):

Olá @MCunha98,

Você pode criar uma estrutura com PHP/Jquery. Onde o ajax ficará como um arquivo centralizador, e toda vez que você for executar um comando, define esse arquivo, enviando valores para ele, recebendo via GET/POST e atribuindo as variaveis via js.

por exemplo:

- menu clientes e menu produtos.
- Clica em menu clientes>novo cadastro
- ao clicar em novo cadastro, faz um .load() do form, onde nesse form estará o ajax. Esse form será chamado por todos os recursos(clientes/produtos, etc...)
- o form receberá um parametro, definindo de qual tela e demais itens definidos como convenção de sua estrutura.

Comment: isso eu ja fiz, a questao e justamente que a medida que a coisa vai crescendo começa a ter várias vezes o mesmo 'blocão' em momentos distintos do codigo e era isso que quero simplificar com uma função que ja faça a interface direta com o ajax

Comment: Experimenta criar uma function nomeFunc(){ colocando o ajax aqui e demais variaveis no success e before }. Então esse arquivo seria referenciado via script src ou inlcude, fazendo a chamada dele com seus parametros